# How do I kill all mobs with a custom name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a minigame on a server, I have command blocks to summon a lot of zombies. All the zombies who are summoned are given the custom name of 'Infected'.

I need a way so when the game is done all the remaining Infected get killed by command blocks. I have tried setting it up so when the minigame is done a command block changes it to peaceful and then to normal again but on servers changing difficulty never really works. The server i'm working on is at 1.7.10. is this even possible in 1.7.10? I know you don't have the @e command.

Answer (score 3):

Use a couple of command blocks to summon thrown potions to kill the zombies:

```
/summon ThrownPotion X Y Z {Potion:{tag:{CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:6,Amplifier:20}]}}}
```

Summon them wherever the zombies can get, and it should kill them. I tried this and it seems to work, but if you encounter any problems, please comment and I will look into it.

Comment: so i don't fully understand the command so correct me if i'm wrong but wouldn't this require me to do this to every single block the zombies can walk cuz they can go quite far. is possible for like one of these commands to summon a potion on every block for like a 100 block radius.

Comment: not every block, but you need to do it on most blocks, spreading them around. You can run the commands a couple of times to make sure the zombies die.

Comment: so there is no way to summon them with like a radius command so i don't have to do this to almost every block?

Comment: @gamer103 No, but a minecart command block using relative coordinates from under the arena may work